# making my theme multisite compatible?

Tags: theme-development, users

I have a wordpress theme that works "OK" as a single user and I have attempted to get it to work as a multi-user unsuccessfully.

There are features missing in multiuser side that are necessary to get it working the way I need it to work, like "theme options".

Here is a snap-shot of theme options http://screencast.com/t/5sx0umfYQs6

I'm thinking it must be a database issue as well as other things... I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific as to what you're actually looking for?  What features are missing?  What is the way you need it to work?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the theme options is available to non Super Admins with WordPress Multisite.  Take a look at this:

http://wpmututorials.com/known-issues/did-your-users-theme-options-and-widgets-page-disappear/

There's a fix described in that posting as well.

Summary: Use the `edit_themes_options` capability, not `edit_themes` for options pages.